# Assigning self as delegate implementation will cause a memory leak?

Tags: swift

Hi I have 2 protocols second one has and reference of first protocol type, and also it returns `self` for that reference. here is the code.

```
protocol MainViewModelInput {
    func loginButtonAction()
    func registerButtonAction()
}

protocol MainViewModelProvider {
    var input: MainViewModelInput { get }
}

extension MainViewModelProvider where Self: MainViewModelInput {
    var input: MainViewModelInput { return self }
}
```

so when I am implementing it like this, does it creates a memory leak?

```
class MainViewModel: MainViewModelProvider, MainViewModelInput {

    private let router: AnyRouter<MainRoute>

    init(router: AnyRouter<MainRoute>) {
        self.router = router
    }
}

extension MainViewModel {

    func loginButtonAction() {
        router.trigger(.login)
    }

    func registerButtonAction() {
        router.trigger(.register)
    }
}
```

My idea is that, if `MainViewController` creates object of type `MainViewModel`, and `input` also holding reference to that object, it will never be released, am I wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Make `input` a `weak var`, which will require your protocol to be a class protocol

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted to know is it necessary? because maybe in other cases someone will want to use it for structs, isn't it possible?

Comment: OK, I didn't look close enough. Since `input` is a computed property, it does not create a reference, so I guess you're good.

Comment: hm, because it only returns self, and not assign delegate as self, it will not create a leak, do I got it correct?

Comment: In your protocol extension you defined `input` as a get-only computed property, so yes, you will be fine.

Comment: great thanks, could you make it as answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally, you want your delegate to be a `weak var` to avoid retain cycles in cases like yours - that's how the delegate pattern is implemented in, for instance, `UIKit` classes like `UITableView`

In your case however, you're defining `input` variable as a get-only computed property. Computed properties in Swift work much like a function- they don't store anything, they merely provide a means retrieve some values indirectly.

It may work, **but** you need to extra careful. An example: let's modify your code, like so:

```
class MainViewModel: MainViewModelProvider, MainViewModelInput {

    private let router: AnyRouter<MainRoute>

    var input: MainViewModelInput?

    init(router: AnyRouter<MainRoute>) {
        self.router = router

        input = self
    }
}
```

What we did: we have overridden the default implementation of `input` property - it's no longer a computed property. And we have also introduced a memory leak - now self holds a strong reference to itself.

So in general: your idea might work, but only if you're extra careful to never override `input` property to be stored and referencing `self`.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is to create a function that checks if `self` is `MainViewModelInput` like this.

```
if let modelInput = self as? MainViewModelInput {
    // Here you should have access to protocol implementation
}
```